# Using parameters and dynamic content in pre-SQL script for Azure Data Factory data flow sink transformation

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline parameter called query_sink (type string) it comes from a database and the posible values for the parameter could be

[image: possible values]

The second record is something like `IF EXISTS(...) DELETE FROM table1 WHERE country = 1`

So, I want to use a dataflow where in the sink transformation use the parameter query_sink.
[image]

Then use it in the pre SQL script in the sink transformation, For now I just pass the parameter without changes like this

[image]

but I have problems when the value in the database is **null**

> 'sink1': There are no batches in the input script."

I'm not sure if the parameter in that case is null or is it as if the parameter didn't receive anything.
What I need is in the case the parameter value is a query(second record of the first image) execut it, but in the other case(first record of the first image) do nothing.

Edit:
the input for the pipeline parameter receive this value

Comment: you have the country column as `null` in some rows? and can you provide the complete expression for `Query_sink` parameter? and also what is your expected output?

Comment: I edited the question, hope this is more clear the complete expresion for **Query_sink** is @concat('\`',pipeline().parameters.Query,'`')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What I need is in the case the parameter value is a query(second record of the first image) execut it, but in the other case(first record of the first image) do nothing.

You can pass the below dynamic content to the dataflow parameter where `query` is a pipeline parameter.

```
@if(greater(length(pipeline().parameters.query),4), concat('''',pipeline().parameters.query,''''),concat('''','DECLARE @id AS INT;',''''))
```

Give this to a string variable and pass the string to the dataflow parameter like below.

[image]

**This is my source table:**

[image]

**target table `final_target2` before deleting:**

[image]

Target table when query parameter value is `delete from final_target2 where country=1;`.

[image]

You can see the records with `country=1` were deleted and new records from `final_source1` were inserted above.

Target table when query parameter value is `NULL`. Here in this case I am Executing a sample query `DECLARE @id AS INT;` which does nothing to target table.

[image]

**My pipeline JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "pipeline1",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Set variable1",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "var",
                    "value": {
                        "value": "@if(greater(length(pipeline().parameters.query),4), concat('''',pipeline().parameters.query,''''),concat('''','DECLARE @id AS INT;',''''))",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Data flow1",
                "type": "ExecuteDataFlow",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set variable1",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "dataflow": {
                        "referenceName": "dataflow1",
                        "type": "DataFlowReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "query_sink": {
                                "value": "@variables('var')",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "compute": {
                        "coreCount": 8,
                        "computeType": "General"
                    },
                    "traceLevel": "Fine"
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "query": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "NULL"
            }
        },
        "variables": {
            "var": {
                "type": "String"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2023-03-27T15:35:50Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

**My dataflow JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "dataflow1",
    "properties": {
        "type": "MappingDataFlow",
        "typeProperties": {
            "sources": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "source2_table",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "source1"
                }
            ],
            "sinks": [
                {
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "final_target",
                        "type": "DatasetReference"
                    },
                    "name": "sink1"
                }
            ],
            "transformations": [],
            "scriptLines": [
                "parameters{",
                "     query_sink as string",
                "}",
                "source(output(",
                "          id as integer,",
                "          country as integer",
                "     ),",
                "     allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     isolationLevel: 'READ_UNCOMMITTED',",
                "     format: 'table') ~> source1",
                "source1 sink(allowSchemaDrift: true,",
                "     validateSchema: false,",
                "     input(",
                "          name as string",
                "     ),",
                "     deletable:false,",
                "     insertable:true,",
                "     updateable:false,",
                "     upsertable:false,",
                "     format: 'table',",
                "     preSQLs:[($query_sink)],",
                "     skipDuplicateMapInputs: true,",
                "     skipDuplicateMapOutputs: true,",
                "     errorHandlingOption: 'stopOnFirstError') ~> sink1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```